# AVFoundation - LayerInstruction + setCropRectangleRamp - how to export properly?

Tags: objective-c, swift, avfoundation

I'm using `AVMutableCompositionLayerInstruction` and the `setCropRectangleRamp` function to create a moving crop effect.

When exporting using `AVAssetExportSession` I set the output and `renderSize` to match the crop dimensions.

However the outputted video doesn't seem to follow the moving crop, but rather just outputs the center of the original video.

How do I get the encoder to encode the pixels inside the moving crop?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. You need to use `setTransformRamp(fromStart:toEnd:timeRange:)` with corresponding parameters!